# Values of $c$ that will make a matrix invertible using Gaussian Elimination

Tags: linear-algebra

For what values of $c$ will $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ c & c^2 \end{bmatrix}$ be invertible? I can't use determinants. I have to use Gaussian elimination. I know that the answer is $c$ can't equal $0$ or $1$ thanks to determinants. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at what you obtain when you take $c$ times the first line to the second line (this is gaussian elimination step), you obtain $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&c^2-c\end{bmatrix}$ this matrix is equivalent via elementary operation to yours and can only be invertible if $c^2-c$ is non null.

Answer (score 0):

Recall: When $\text{det}A = 0$, $\text{ker}A = \{0\}$, since for the matrix to be invertible, a homomorphism $\phi:A \to A$ must be an isomorphism (i.e. $A \cong A$). By definition, $\phi$ is only an isomorphism when $\text{Im} \phi = A$ and $\text{ker} \phi = {0}$.

So, we must show that $A$ is invertible by showing, via Gaussian-Elimination, that $\text{ker}A = \{0\}$.

When we reduce the matrix $A$ via row operations, the columns in which the leading element is $0$ are the very vectors in the basis of the kernel of $A$. So, given our matrix $A$, it can clearly be simplified via row operations to $A_{rref} = \left[\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & c(c-1) \end{array} \right] = \left[\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right]$.

So, clearly $c(c-1) = 0$ when $c = 0$, and $c = 1$ and we know that when $c(c-1) = 0$, $\text{ker}A = \{0\}$.

Therefore, for $c = 0$ and $c = 1$, the matrix $A$ is invertible.